# Dynamically populate select box from database base on input text of a specified length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be able to dynamically populate a html select base on input text value. This need to be automatically triggered once the text box value is 8 characters of more. User should not have to tab or click to see the populated value. Here's what I have so far but this is only fire when the text box loses focus.

```
//Html code
<input id=InputText name=InputText onblur="populateListBox();" onchange="CheckInputLength();" onkeydown="CheckInputLength();" value="" onfocus="this.select();">
```

//Javascript code

```
function CheckInputLength()
{
    if($("#InputText").val().length >= 8)
        populateListBox();
}

function populateListBox()
{   
            $.get("???", function( data ) {
                $('#listBox').children().remove();
                var options = data;

                $("#listBox").append( options );
                $("#listBox").html( data );

            });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#InputText').keypress(function (event) {
    var $inputText = $(this);
    // Before keypress.
    setTimeout(function () {
        // After keypress.
        if ($inputText.val().length >= 8) { populateListBox(); }
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: WOW! I have tried your solution and it worked beautifully. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Select2 which sounds like it has all of the functionality your looking for and plus some: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

```
$("#InputText").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 8,
  ajax: {
    url: "???",
    // your other options
  }
});
```